# How can I change the Visual Studio default Form font?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I had some problems with my Windows fonts, because of that, VS changed the default Form font to Arial. How can I go back to Microsoft Sans Serif ?

I know that I can change the Font at the Form propertie, but I would have to change it at all forms that I create.

Edit:
I found out how I've messed up with the windows Fonts, I deleted all entries of the Win.ini file because my filepath was null and **"If this parameter is NULL, the function searches the Win.ini file."**

```
[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "GetPrivateProfileSectionNamesA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(byte[] lpszReturnBuffer, int nSize, string lpFileName);
```

As stuard said, VS gets the font from DEFAULT_GUI_FONT. I still don't know how to reset it back to Microsoft Sans Serif.

Comment: You could [try editing WinGDI.h](http://xkcd.com/349/)

Answer (score 3):

It may be Windows which is at fault rather than Visual Studio, as according to [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/KDente/archive/2005/03/13/394499.aspx) the forms query Windows for `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT`.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are right, how can I change it? DEFAULT_GUI_FONT maybe have changed after almost all my fonts were deleted...

Comment: You may have to reinstall Windows..

Comment: "DEFAULT_GUI_FONT maybe have changed after almost all my fonts were deleted", and the true cause of the problem is revealed... :)

Comment: yeah I know why, but how can I reset it? :P

Comment: You will have to do it in regedit in the windows registry